# How to map a key unless Control is hold down or that key is pressed with Control simultaneously

Tags: autohotkey

The following code maps `PgUp` (resp. `PgDn`) to `WheelUp` (resp. `WheelDn`) unless `Control` is pressed down.
For example If several tabs in firefox are opend and if I first hold down `Control` then press `PgDn` I go to the next tab as desired. But If I press `Control` and `PgDn` simultaneously I go to the next tab and I have also the effect of  `WheelDown`. How to prevent this `WheelDown` in this situation?

In other words I would like a mapping
`Pgdn-->WheelDown` if neither `Control` is hold down nor `Pgdn` and `Control` are pressed simultaneously.

```
#If (NOT (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))
PgUp::WheelUp
PgDn::WheelDown
#If
```

Comment: Have you tried it as standalone script? Works for me.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it as standalone script, I have the same problem. To see the problem, please open a firefox with several opened tabs and try to do several `Ctrl+pagedown" to see what I mean. If I hold down Control and do several Pagedown I don't have problem. But when I press both Control and Page down and release both and do the same thing I have the problem.

Comment: Why not answer your own question, rather than provide it in an edit? It is [better form](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow to do so

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis done.

Comment: I believe you can also accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found this solution:

```
~PgDn::while (NOT (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))
Send {WheelDown}

~PgUp::while (NOT (GetKeyState("Control", "P")))
Send {WheelUp}
```